# Exclude a folder from glob pattern matching

Tags: javascript, glob, prettier

Using [Prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) to format js code.
Prettier seems to be using [globby](https://github.com/sindresorhus/globby) under the hood.

I tried the following:

```
$ prettier './**/*.{js, css}' '!assets/**'
$ prettier './**/*.{js, css}' '!(assets/**)'
$ prettier './**/*.{js, css}' '!assets/**/*.*'
$ prettier './**/*.{js, css}' '!(assets/**/*.*)'
$ prettier './**/*.{js, css}' 'assets/**/!*.*'
```

And in all cases, files in the `assets` folder were included.

What's the correct way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's the PR](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/pull/2356) where that was merged. [Here's the syntax](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/2332). Here's what I have working in my `package.json`:

```
"prettier-fix": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,json,ts,tsx,md,mdx,css,html,yml,yaml,scss}\" \"!\\.next/**\""
```

Lint all matching except `.next` directory. Note the quotes.

Comment: For anyone using a create-react-app project with `"prettier": "^2.0.5"` and want to exclude the build folder, here is a working the script: `"format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,json,css,html}\" \"!build/**\""`

Answer (score 5):

You can now exclude directories with the `!` character. For example this command would format all `.js` and `.css` files in-place, excluding anything in the `assets` directory.

```
"prettier --write **/*.{js, css} !assets/**"
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently impossible. 
But already fixed https://github.com/prettier/prettier/pull/2356. Just wait new version.